# Accessing the database is very slow from a hosted website and fast when accessed from localhost

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, sql-server-2012

We've been having a problem which seems to have just sprung out of nowhere. We have a NopCommerce website which our client has hosted off his own server. We have 1 web server which has Windows 2008R2 IIS 7.5 and a database server which has Windows 2012 and Sql Server 2012 Standard. The website has a SSL certificate from GoDaddy.

Since about a couple of weeks, we've been facing severe performance problems. Selects seems to work okay, but when we need an update or an insert in the database, it takes a really long time. So we added some logging and this is what we found out.

If we host the website locally, i.e. via localhost, updates take 750ms
And for the hosted website, it takes 10-19s for a single update statement. And if I copy the website and take a db backup and host it on my laptop which has Windows 10 pro. Update statements take 80ms.

Just so I am clear, the website loads fine. All select queries work great, its just when we add a product to the cart or update an admin setting when the performance goes to the dogs.

Could someone point us in the right direction? We're not sure where the problem lies.

**Update:** Here's some more info. This is what we've done so far. We first thought this was a problem with the IIS site itself. So we created a new IIS site and added the relavent bindings. But the site was still slow. We also have a development site which has a different external IP address. And this site works absolutely fine. We even tried to make this site point to our production folder. And it was fast. We've asked our network admin and he says everything is fine. Is there something we're missing

Answer (score 0):

So what you're saying is when you host it locally, it's loads faster compared to when it's hosted not locally? There may be some networking issues on the hosted websites end, but it's always going to be faster being accessed locally vs. accessing the resources from a hosted location.

Comment: I understand that. But would there be such a huge difference when accessing the database? I can understand a certain delay. But a 18 second delay seems a bit too much doesn't it. And the website loads fine. So select queries work great. The problem starts when you try to add a product or update an admin setting in the website. I've updated my question so I make more sense.

Comment: There could be if the location serving the database is having network congestion. There are a lot of variables at play. I'd generally assume to start at a wider range of troubleshooting, starting with the SQL servers network statistics, CPU/Memory usage, if there have been any recent usage changes. 

Once you've worked your way up the stack you could then get into the more nitty gritty and trace out SQL execution plans etc. I'm not personally a SQL DB admin, but the SQL stack exchange is a great resource and has tons if information in regards to this.Reflink: https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No there isn't the server is in Australia and there aren't a lot of users online right now. I executed sp_monitor on the sql server and it doesnt show any huge network usage or cpu usage or memory usage. Here are some stats
cpu_busy  : 187715(19)-211%                   io_busy : 1899(0)-0% idle
  832879(47)-522%.  Here's the screenshot of task manager https://imgur.com/a/Bd3Yqmo. And btw the admin setting update is still running.

Comment: The only reason I'm not posting this in the dba forum is because I dont think this is a db Problem. The database table in question here has 2000 rows